# Compilation from source: error

Tags: magento2.1.0

I have this problem:

> Compilation from source:  frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/en_US/css/email-fonts.less {{{
>   Compilation from source:  frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/en_US/css/email-fonts.less }}{{
>   Compilation from source:  frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/en_US/css/email-fonts.less }}{{
>   Compilation from source:  frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/en_US/css/email-fonts.less }}{{theme}}}

problem shows at deploying the file `frontend/my_vendor/my_theme/en_US/css/email-fonts.css`

I am new to Magento and I do not know what to fix. My version is 2.1.0

`.htaccess` file is in `pub\static`

view source shows `/pub/static/frontend/my_vendor/new/el_GR/`

`el_gr` is created after `en_us` I think so no theme is showing

data show correctly on a no theme page

found something here but no answer available or understood by me

[Static content deploy - Compilation from source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127069/static-content-deploy-compilation-from-source)

plz help ...... thank you

Answer (score 0):

What if you rename the source frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/email-fonts.less file to _email-fonts.less (notice the underscore)

I was just getting the same notices/errors with a less file on a theme I'm trying to fix (Smartwave/porto). As soon as added the underscore in front of the filename Magento stopped complaining during static content deploy.